# DropDown em swift

Tags: ios, swift, dropdown, button

Estou a usar um tipo de dropdown usando este projeto [1](https://github.com/UnicornTV/Make-a-Dropdown-Menu-in-iOS), e agora queria selecionar um dos itens que se encontra dentro dela e fechar a dropdown e o item escolhido aparecer na label do botão isto tudo em swift, alguem me pode ajudar aqui?

Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro vc tem q criar um IBOutlet para o botão que vai ter o seu titulo alterado: (Não esqueça de ligar ele ao botão na storyboard)

```
@IBOutlet var botao: UIButton!
```

Lá no "func createPicker()" acrescente a seguinte linha no loop em que cria as opções do popup:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: "clicado:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

A linha acima diz para o botão que está sendo criado, qual o método q ele deve chamar ao ser clicado.

Então vc cria o método:

```
func clicado(sender : UIButton){
   // acha o titulo de acordo com a tag do botão clicado
   let feeling = properties.moods[sender.tag].first!
   // atribui o titulo achado ao botão do IBOutlet criado
   self.botao.setTitle(feeling.1, forState: .Normal)
   // fecha o picker
   self.closePicker()
}
```

Comment: CCastro, sabe me dizer o motivo dos dois pontos no final da string no  nome do método na action (clicado)?

Comment: Vc fala esses dois pontos? ->  func clicado(sender : UIButton)    ele especifica o tipo q será recebido pelo método. No caso, o sender receberá um UIButton, ou seja, o UIBUtton q foi clicado. Então quando eu faço sender.tag mais abaixo, estou pegando o tag do UIButton que foi clicado, assim, consigo identificar qual foi a opção

Comment: Não, dentro da string do addTarget mesmo... action: "clicado:"

Comment: Não sei se ficou claro?

Comment: Sim ficou, obg! Porém é bem estranho vc passar um parametro self e no segundo parametro ser obrigado a colocar dois pontos para que o primeiro parametro funcione.

Comment: Jadson, uma correção. Olhando a documentação recentemente, o primeiro parâmetro não se trata do botão, mas do target. Ou seja, a classe onde a função a ser chamada foi definida.